# What is the difference between a Josephson junction and a superconducting tunnel junction?

Tags: superconductivity, josephson-junction

I am wondering if there is any difference between a Josephson junctions and superconducting tunnel junctions.

I appreciate a good explanation.

Comment: This question is not entirely clear, it could be better to see where you found the word *superconducting tunnel junctions*. As far as I can see, it can mean 2 things : either a short insulating barrier between two superconductors, or a barrier between a superconductor and something else. The Josephson physics is present only in between two superconducting electrodes, and in that case, the name *tunnel* is used to say that the flow of electrons will be small, and the junction short. In the second case (S/N interface), there is no Josephson physics

Comment: An other possible distinction is the mathematical method used to resolve the problem. In a Josephson junction one may want to count over the Andreev bound states which carry the current inside the bridge, whereas in the tunnel approximation one uses a tunnel matrix, and calculate the current at second order in the tunnelling amplitude.

Comment: Finally, *tunnel* usually refer to a short, disordered interface between two materials, where dc current can flow. So I'd say that a *tunnel* Josephson junction is one kind of a Josephson junction. What is unclear in your question is that you did not talk about a *tunnel Josephson* but you mention a *Josephson* and a *tunnel* junction. *Tunnel* just means usually what I defined in this comment. *Josephson* means two superconductors interrupted by an insulator, a normal metal, a ferromagnet, a semiconducting materials, or any combinations of these.